# Passing PHP Variable to controller and get it back

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii

I have a variable and I want to update the value in the controller and render a part of the page based on  the value.

This works very well in the first time but the variable doesn't get the value, stay with the first. Here my code:

Model:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new CadTeste;
    $teste=1;

    if(isset($_POST['CadTeste']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['CadTeste'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->icd_teste));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'teste'=>$teste,
    ));
}
```

Form:

```
    <div id="data">
   <?php $this->renderPartial('_ajaxContent', array('teste'=>$teste)); ?>
</div>

<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Alterar Num',CController::createUrl('CadTeste/UpdateAjax'),
array('type'=>'POST',                               
      'data' => array('teste'=> $teste),
      'update' => '#data'          
          )
         ); ?>
```

The Controler

```
public function actionUpdateAjax()
{
    $teste = $_POST['teste'];
    $teste += 10;
    $this->renderPartial('_ajaxContent', array('teste'=>$teste), false, true);
}
```

And the _ajaxContent

```
<?php echo $teste; ?>
```

Every time I click on the button I get the value "11" instead of "11, 21, 31, 41".

How can I do that? Should I change the value every time in the controller?

Comment: do you try define variable as `static`?

Comment: Nothing happen, still getting 1,11,11,11,11,11... Btw im using Yii framework...

Comment: Is $_POST getting populated? What is happening in the console of Firebug when you click the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Using Sessions . This Works for me

View File

```
<?php Yii::app()->session['teste']=$teste ?>
<div id='data'>
 <?php $this->renderPartial('_ajaxContent', array('teste'=>$teste)); ?>
</div>
<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Alterar Num',$this->createUrl('CadTeste/UpdateAjax'),
array('type'=>'POST',                               
     // 'data' => array('teste'=> $teste),
      'update' => '#data'          
          )
 ); ?>
```

Your Controller

```
public function actionUpdateAjax()
    {
        $teste = Yii::app()->session['teste'];
        $teste += 10;
        $this->renderPartial('_ajaxContent', array('teste'=>$teste));
        unset(Yii::app()->session['teste']);
        Yii::app()->session['teste']=$teste;

    }
```

And Your Model As it Is

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new CadTeste;
    $teste=1;

    if(isset($_POST['CadTeste']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['CadTeste'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->icd_teste));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'teste'=>$teste,
    ));
}
```

Not sure if this is your problem, but renderPartial() does not play well with AJAX. It is a known Yii issue:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/24699-yii-20-ajaxrenderpartial-conflict/

Comment: If the answer is correct mark it as correct so that answer will be useful for some one in future

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for the view:

```
<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Alterar Num',CController::createUrl('CadTeste/UpdateAjax',array('teste'=>$teste)),
array('type'=>'POST',                               
      'update' => '#data'          
      )
); ?>
```

---

This for the controller:

```
public function actionUpdateAjax($teste)
{
    $teste += 10;
    $this->renderPartial('_ajaxContent', array('teste'=>$teste));
}
```

This way you can POST to action/ajaxupdate/teste/1

Its called `Parameter Binding`, the parameter in $teste is populated automatically from the url, if it's not present, it will give you an error. (You could put a default value $teste=1 to make it optional)